# Parse Excel file and create a hash structure(key/value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, data-structures, ecmascript-5

I have an Excel file with the following template.

| Name, Surname, Class |
| --- |
| Alex, Smith, B1, |
| Maria, Smith, B2 |

The Excel file has multiple sheets with data in different languages.

I want to read from the Excel file and to create a hash structure (key/value) because I want to add later more information in each entry.

I have achieved to set the keys names for each entry but I cannot understand how I can import the values for each entry.

You can see the required format of the structure here:

```html
var arr = [{
    "name":{default:"Alex", cellId:"B1"},
        "surname":{default:"Smith", cellId:"B2"},
        "class":{default: "B1", cellId:"B3"}
        },
        {
    "name":{default:"Maria", cellId:"C1"},
        "surname":{default:"Smith", cellId:"C2"},
        "class":{default: "B1", cellId:"C3"}
        } ]
```

```js
$("#btn").on("change", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var files = e.target.files;
  var i, f;
  for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: "buffer",
        blankRows: true,
        defval: ' '
      });
      var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
      var theQuestionLanguage = sheet_name_list; //english
      var theExcelDataArray = [];
      var test;
      var data = [];
      var headers = {};

      sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y) {
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[y];
        var headers = {};
        var data = [];
        for (z in worksheet) {
          //parse out the column, row, and value
          var col = z.substring(0, 1);
          var row = parseInt(z.substring(1));
          var value = worksheet[z].v;

          //store header names
          if (row == 1 && !headers[value]) {
            headers[value] = {};
          }

          console.log(headers);
          if ((headers[value]) && (row !== 1)) {
            headers[value].default = "value"
            console.log("headers");
          }
        }

        //drop those first two rows which are empty

      });
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Convert excel file to CSV format]

First of all, Save As your Excel file in CSV format.
After that, go to this website : [Let's go](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm). In this website you can add for information in your each entry and convert them into key/value pair.

I hope this this above information will help you.